# How to add a logo to the upper-right or bottom-right of each page in beamer

Tags: beamer

Friends, I'd like to add a logo to the upper-right or bottom-right of each page in beamer. But I cannot figure it out. I can only add it to the footline. In this case, the title and name are omitted. How can I solve it?
Here is a minimal example of my Beamer TeX. Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath, multicol,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl} 

\usepackage{grffile,threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig,graphbox} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setbeamertemplate{caption,footline}[numbered]

\def\name{Yan}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    urlcolor = blue,
    pdfauthor = {\name},
}
    \title[Introduction ]{An Introduction} 
\author{
    Yan}
\institute[CU] 

\medskip

\date{\today} % Date


\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
    
    \everymath{\displaystyle}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage 
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Outline} 
        \tableofcontents 
    \end{frame}

   
\section{Background}
   
    \begin{frame}{Why}

a integrated 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please format code as code and not as a quote. Use the `{}` or ctrl+k.

Comment: I do this, but based on the tree layouts. I suppose it wouldn't work here.

Comment: `\def\name` is a really awful idea. Please, don't do this. Some of the packages you are loading make no sense at all with `beamer`. `multicol`, `indentfirst` and probably the caption and figure packages. You don't need to load things like `graphicx` and `table` should be passed to `xcolor` rather than `colortbl`.  `textpos` doesn't seem the best idea, either, but that's just a hunch and could be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you use the `\logo` macro. 
Simply put it in document's preamble.

```
\logo{\includegraphics{pic}}
```

it puts the content at the bottom-right of each page.

Comment: @Yang-Hui Please think about accepting the answers that helped you to solve your problems. You haven't accept any answer and this makes your questions to seem as unsolved (and this is bad for the community).

Answer (score 0):

For the **top-right** corner, use

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}\hspace{0.2cm}\vspace{-1cm}}
```

Adjust the parameters (`width`, `hspace`, `vspace`) accordingly.